# Turning monitor off using mono (C#)

Tags: c#, linux, mono, debian

I have the following code that turns the monitors off in Windows which I currently use on a button click;

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
const int SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170;
const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
const int MONITOR_ON = -1;
const int MONITOR_OFF = 2;
const int MONITOR_STANBY = 1;
int onFlag = 0;

private void MonitorOff()
{
    SendMessage(-1, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, MONITOR_OFF);
    onFlag = 1;
}

private void MonitorOn()
{
    if (onFlag == 1)
    {
        SendMessage(-1, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, MONITOR_ON);
        onFlag = 0;
    }
}
```

This code works fine. I now want to do the same thing under Linux (Debian if it makes a difference) using mono. Obviously I can't make use of user32.dll so was wondering if anyone knew how to do this?

I guess I could just make use of [these commands](https://superuser.com/a/31885/114431) if there is no built-in way of achieving this...

Comment: So... why not use those commands if they're there? Controlling hardware isn't really "built-in" to any high-level programming language since it's usually too platform-dependent.

Comment: @millimoose I'm pretty sure that user32.dll will not be there on linux.

Comment: @kenny, the "commands" that millimoose is talking about are the `xset` and `setterm` commands in the link, not the user32.dll stuff. And as for Luke's question, millimoose is correct. I'm not aware of any Mono libraries that do this. You'll likely need to call `xset` and `setterm` to do this.

Comment: @Pete Exactly, I was referring to the last sentence.

Comment: Alternatively, you could look at how `xset` is implemented and call those functions on Linux using `DllImport` as well, but I'd avoid that unless it's absolutely straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of extra information on this; I am using a raspberry pi and the xset and setterm commands only blank the screen. In order to actually turn off the screen I had to make use of `tvservice -o` (turns off) and `tvservice -p` (turn on). I did not find any built in way in mono to perform the same actions.

Comment: This should be an edit to your initial post rather than an answer.

Comment: But it does answer the question that there was no code to achieve what I wanted in mono as well as a little bit of extra information as to how I achieved the same desired outcome?